# Create Array from File Import in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that reads a file formated as below:

city    city    weight

It will be used to create a graph. What I have below isn't working and I don't understand why. I am admittedly pretty shakey when it comes to working with char arrays and arrays of strings.

int main() {

```
    // Create an empty graph
    graph_t* graph = create_graph();
    // string buffer and tokens

    char buffer[25];
    char* source;
    char* dest;
    char* weight;
    int key, a, b, c, d, e, f;
    char cities[25][25];

    //Open file and Read data from datafile city.dat
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("city.dat","r");

    if(fp==NULL){
       printf("no such file exists\n");
       return 0;
    }
    b = 0;
    while(fgets(buffer, 25, fp)!=NULL){
      printf("inside while loop\n");
      printf("before tokenization\n");
      source = strtok(buffer, " ");
      printf("after tokenization\n");
      char tempSource[40];
      strcpy(tempSource,source);
      printf("tempSource = %s\n", tempSource);
      int size = sizeof(cities)/sizeof(cities[0]);
      printf("size = %d\n", size);

      for(e=0;e<size;e++){
            printf("inside first loop\n");
            char temp[40];
            printf("before strcopy of cities[e]\n");
            printf("%s\n", cities[e]);
            strcpy(temp,cities[e]);
```

What I am trying to do is add the strings I'm tokenizing to the cities array only if it doesn't already exist. I've been working on this for days and have made no progress and really don't know what to do next. Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

When I print the value of cities[e] I either get a blank or a memory address.

Comment: can you include the rest of the code please?  or if it's too much, a minimal reproduction?

Comment: You never assign any value to any element of `cities`.